# decomposing positive definite matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

My question is simple : i know that a positive definite matrix M can be written as : $M = A^TA$ where A is any matrix (i guess).

My question is : given a positive definite matrix M, how can i find the associated matrix A.

Is this matrix A unique or not.

Thank you.

Comment: Uniqueness: of course not, as, e.g., every orthogonal matrix $P$ will yield $P^TP=I$. How to determine $A$: since $M$ is symmetric positive definite, it is diagonalizable, and the change of basis matrix $P$ can be chosen to be orthogonal: $M=PDP^T$. Now, $D$ is diagonal with positive coefficients on the diagonal; take its square root $S$, i.e., $S$ is diagonal, $S^2=D$ and the diagonal coefficients of $S$ are positive. Then set $A=SP^T$ and you'll have $A^TA=PS^TSP^T=PDP^T=M$.

Answer (score 1):

(Presumably the underlying field is real.) If such an $A$ exists, it must be invertible. Therefore, it has a unique [polar decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_decomposition) $A=UP$, where $P$ is positive definite and $U$ is real orthogonal. Hence $M=A^TA=P^2$ and $P$ must be equal to $M^{1/2}$, the (unique) positive square root of $M$. In short, when $M$ is positive definite,

> $M=A^TA$ if and only if $A=UM^{1/2}$ for some real orthogonal matrix $U$.

As $U$ is arbitrary and $M$ is nonzero, $A$ is *never* unique. In particular, if $M=A^TA$, we also have $M=(-A)^T(-A)$.

Answer (score 0):

You can perform so called Cholesky Factorization to compute a triangular matrix $L$ such that $M=LL^{T}$. Cholesky factorization is unique, however finding matrix $A$ so that $M=A^{T}A$ is not unique. For instance, if EVD of $M$ is $M=Q^{T}DQ$, then $A=Q^{T}D^{1/2}V$, where $V$ is any orthonormal matrix